# Regex removing all symbols before specified

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following script in perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "int array[WIDTH][HEIGHT]";

$string =~ s#.*\[##;

print($string."\n");
```

expected output:

> WIDTH][HEIGHT]

actual output:

> HEIGHT]

What is wrong with this regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `.*` lazy by adding `?`:

```
$string =~ s#.*?\[##;
               ^
```

This will make the `.*` match as little as possible and hence stop at the first `[` without consuming it.

You can also use `$string =~ s#[^\[]*\[##;` to do the same thing, and `[^\[]` cannot consume `[`, so no need for laziness.

Comment: Thanks! It helped. I will accept your answer in next 15 minutes.

Comment: +1 for the little carat on the next line :) (and cos it's correct)

Comment: Better yet, make the pattern more specific: `s{ \A [^\[]* \[ }{}msx`